# How to open an xml using c# and datagridview?

Tags: c#

I managed to open an xml that was saved on my PC for test purposes or to display it with the datagridview, but this does not work with an xml that is on an external server. Do I have to change something in my code or what could be the problem? Thanks in advance! :)
with following code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"test.xml");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: Do both XML files have the same structure? Does the server version actually have data in it? Are there any permissions on the server that would cause the file not to be read? Do you actually have any error logs from the server?

Comment: `"test.xml"` This doesn't look like a path to an external server

Comment: `dataSet.ReadXml(@"test.xml");` most likely your test.xml file is not in the same folder as the executing assembly.

Comment: the "test.xml" is on my laptop. The structure of the xml from the server looks as same as on my laptop. Permissions is a good notice but I checked it already.

Comment: does it make a difference if it is "/" or "\" in the xml file? Because on the external they are "/" like that

Comment: What do you mean by ```/``` or ```\``` in the XML file?